# Array.shift() in a while(Array.length) give error in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm currently implementing A* in typescript and use an array as a queue, and my while loop continue as long as there is item in the queue, but typescript doesn't understand that inside the loop Array.shift() can't return undefined.

```
interface edge {
    weight:number;
    vertex:Vertex;
}

interface Vertex {
    name:string;
    successor:edge[];
    heuristic:number;
    dist:number;
    parent?:Vertex;
    visited:boolean;
}

function Astar(startingNode:Vertex, goal:Vertex, heuristicFunc?:(node:Vertex, goal:Vertex) => number):Vertex[]|null {
    startingNode.dist = 0;
    const queue = [startingNode];
    while(queue.length) {
        queue.sort((a, b) => a.dist + a.heuristic - b.dist - b.heuristic);
        let currentNode = queue.shift();
        if(currentNode == goal) {
            const path:Vertex[] = []
            while(currentNode) {
                path.unshift(currentNode);
                currentNode = currentNode.parent;
            }
            return path;
        }
        currentNode.visited = true;
        currentNode.successor.forEach(({weight, vertex}) => {
            if(currentNode.dist + weight < vertex.dist) {
                vertex.dist = currentNode.dist + weight;
                vertex.parent = currentNode;
                vertex.visited = false;
            }
        })
        currentNode.successor.filter(({vertex})=> !vertex.visited && !queue.includes(vertex)).forEach(({vertex}) => {
            if(heuristicFunc) vertex.heuristic = heuristicFunc(vertex, goal);
            queue.push(vertex);
        })
    }
    return null;
}
```

when I compile it, it give me this error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
Astar.ts:29:9 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

29         currentNode.visited = true;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~
Astar.ts:30:9 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

30         currentNode.successor.forEach(({weight, vertex}) => {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~
Astar.ts:31:16 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

31             if(currentNode.dist + weight < vertex.dist) {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
Astar.ts:32:31 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

32                 vertex.dist = currentNode.dist + weight;
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~
Astar.ts:37:9 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

37         currentNode.successor.filter(({vertex})=> !vertex.visited && !queue.includes(vertex)).forEach(({vertex}) => {
```

here are my compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Do I really need to implicitly check if its undefined? or is there an other option?

Comment: Yes, that's how `shift` is typed. But usually, there is a better option - it depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish with the code inside the loop.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I removed all unnecessary line of my A* code and uploaded it instead if you want to take a look

Comment: That looks reasonable. You should probably just add a `!` to the end of the `shift` call to indicate that the value won't be undefined. I often see people using mutator methods unnecessarily when manipulating data structures, but for complicated algorithms like this one, `shift` could well be the clearest way to do it.

Comment: I suppose you could change it to: `while (true) { /* sort */ let currentNode = queue.shift(); if (!currentNode) return null;` if you really wanted to, but it's not much different. Using `!` is fine

Comment: @CertainPerformance works perfectly! just had to change a little the path reconstruction loop but now all errors are gone! thanks you very much

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did not know about the ! operator, you learned me something today :)